# Fechas mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito traer algunos datos de una tabla persona en especial el campo nacimiento, pero necesito que en nacimiento sólo me muestre el año y no lo consigo hacer, me arroja vació. De que otra forma se puede solución el problema.

**Nota:** Colocando solo la consulta para probarla en phpmyadmin funciona, pero cuando la agrego a la función no.

**Código de la función con la consulta**

```js
 public static function getById2($idPersona){
   $sql = "select documento, nombre1, nombre2, apellido1, apellido2, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM nacimiento) from ".self::$tablename." where idPersona=$idPersona";
  $query = Executor::doit($sql);
  return Model::one($query[0],new personaData());
 }
```

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La clase Model**

```js
<?php
class Model {

 public static function exists($modelname){
  $fullpath = self::getFullpath($modelname);
  $found=false;
  if(file_exists($fullpath)){
   $found = true;
  }
  return $found;
 }

 public static function getFullpath($modelname){
  return "core/app/model/".$modelname.".php";
 }

 public static function many($query,$aclass){
  $cnt = 0;
  $array = array();
  while($r = $query->fetch_array()){
   $array[$cnt] = new $aclass;
   $cnt2=1;
   foreach ($r as $key => $v) {
    if($cnt2>0 && $cnt2%2==0){ 
     $array[$cnt]->$key = $v;
    }
    $cnt2++;
   }
   $cnt++;
  }
  return $array;
 }
 //////////////////////////////////
 public static function one($query,$aclass){
  $cnt = 0;
  $found = null;
  $data = new $aclass;
  while($r = $query->fetch_array()){
   $cnt=1;
   foreach ($r as $key => $v) {
    if($cnt>0 && $cnt%2==0){ 
     $data->$key = $v;
    }
    $cnt++;
   }

   $found = $data;
   break;
  }
  return $found;
 }

}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Le has hecho seguimiento a lo que pasa dentro de `getById2()`? Me refiero a imprimir los valores de `$idPersona`, `$sql`, `$query`, etc... De todos modos, cuando obtienes el Año en tu `select`, si no das un alias a dicha columna generada, sólo podrías acceder a su valor por su índice: si dentro de `Model::one()` accedes por el nombre de columna, entonces eso podría ser el motivo de la ausencia de valor. Sería bueno que nos mostraras el código de `Model::one()` también...

Comment: @quinqui ya actualice la pregunta y agregue el código de la clase model

Comment: Perfecto. Ahora hazle el seguimiento a `Model::one()`, imprimiendo las variables que usas dentro, para saber qué tienen realmente. Es una forma de depurar.

Comment: ¿Dónde se llama a `getById2()`? ¿Con qué valores?

Comment: Como comentario, sin ver el código que falta: no crees consultas concatenando cadenas de texto. Puedes crear problemas de seguridad graves como la inyección SQL. Sería mejor que realizaras consultas preparadas/parametrizadas.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacerlo de dos formas en el query o en el código.

Para hacerlo en el query podrías escribir tu código así:

```
    $sql = "SELECT documento, nombre1, nombre2, apellido1, apellido2, YEAR(nacimiento) as anio FROM ".self::$tablename." where idPersona=$idPersona"
```

**YEAR(nacimiento)** es la función de MySQL que saca la fecha de nacimiento a variables tipo DATE o DATETIME, si la variable no es de ninguno de estos tipos, no va a funcionar

Para hacerlo en el código la forma más fácil sería hacer un explode al resultado del query y agarrar el valor del año, algo parecido a esto:

```
<?php
    $lstrFecha = '2018-10-22';
    $larrFecha = explode('-',$lstrFecha);
    echo $larrFecha[0];
?>
```

Comment: Hice lo que dijiste pero sigue sin funcionar